# How to grow UIlabel into scrollable UIlabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, constraints

I'm trying to create a label that fits the text size. But if the text is too long it make scroll

I am trying something like that.

```
[containerView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView_
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1.0f
                                                               constant:300]];

[containerView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bigMargin-[scrollLabel_]-bigMargin-|"
                                                                                   options:0
                                                                                   metrics:metrics
                                                                                     views:views]];

[containerView_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-bigMargin-[scrollLabel_]-bigMargin-|"
                                                                                   options:0
                                                                                   metrics:metrics
                                                                                     views:views]];


[scrollLabel_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[messageLabel_]-0-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:metrics
                                                                           views:views]];
[scrollLabel_ addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[messageLabel_]-0-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:metrics
                                                                           views:views]];
```

The purpose is to show a popup with text and other stuff.
I expected my container view to grow up to 300 in height and if the message was bigger than scrolling.
But my UIScrollView gets a frame of 0 and the only thing that grows is the contentsize

Any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I think UILabel are not meant to do that. You may consider using a `UITextView`. You may need to enable the scroll with:

```
textView.scrollEnabled = true
```

Comment: First I tried with UiTextView, but I had the same problem

Comment: Please see my response. If it doesn't work can you please post some code? so that we can see what you have tried.